# Laravel - Eloquent relation whereHas one or more other relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm learning Laravel and Laravel eloquent at the moment and now I try to solve a problem using relations in Laravel.
This is what I want to archive:

The database holds many sport clubs. A sport club has a lot of teams. Each team has games. The teams table has a column named `club_id`. Now I want to create Eloquent relations to get all games of a club.

Here is what I got so far:

**Club model**

`id => PRIMARY`

```
public function games()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Games')->whereHas('homeTeam')->orWhereHas('guestTeam');
    }
```

**Game model**

`home_id => FOREIGN KEY of team ; guest_id => FOREIGN KEY of team`

```
public function homeTeam()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Team','home_id')->where('club_id','=', $club_id);
    }

    public function guestTeam()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Team','guest_id')->where('club_id','=', $club_id);
    }
```

**Team model**

`id => PRIMARY ; club_id => FOREIGN`

In my controller all I want to do is `Club::findOrFail($id)->games()`

Executing the code above returns a SQL error that the games table does not have a column named `club_id`.

What is the correct way to create this kind of relation?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Thanks to Nikola Gavric I've found a way to get all Games - but only where club teams are the home or away team.

Here is the relation:

```
public function games()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Game','App\Models\Team','club_id','home_id');
    }
```

How is it possible to get the games where the home_id OR the guest_id matches a team of the club? The last parameter in this function does not allow an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is method to retrieve a "distant relationship with an intermediary" and it is called [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

There is also a concrete example on how to use it which includes `Post`, `Country` and `User`, but I think it will be sufficient to give you a hint on how to create `games` relationship inside of a `Club` model. [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) is a link, but when you open it, search for `hasManyThrough` keyword and you will see an example.

P.S: With right `keys naming` you could achieve it with:

```php
public function games()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Games', 'App\Models\Teams');
}
```

---

### EDIT #01

Since you have 2 types of teams, you can create 2 different relationships where each relationship will get you one of the type you need. Like this:

```php
public function gamesAsHome()
{
    return $this
        ->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Games', 'App\Models\Teams', 'club_id', 'home_id');
}

public function gamesAsGuests()
{
    return $this
        ->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Games', 'App\Models\Teams', 'club_id', 'guest_id');
}
```

---

### EDIT #02

**Merging Relationships**: To merge these 2 relationships, you can use [`merge()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-merge) method on the `Collection` instance, what it will do is, it will append all the records *from second collection* into the *first one*.

```php
$gamesHome = $model->gamesAsHome;
$gamesGuests = $model->gamesAsGuests;
$games = $gamesHome->merge($gamesGuests);

return $games->unique()->all();
```

Thanks to @HCK for pointing out that you might have duplicates after the merge and that [`unique()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-unique) is required to get the *unique games after the merge*.

---

### EDIT #03

`sortBy` also offers a `callable` instead of a `attribute name` in cases where `Collection` contains `numerical indexing`. You can sort your `Collection` like this:

```php
$merged->sortBy(function($game, $key) {
    return $game->created_at;
});
```

Comment: I almost got it! I'm using this here right now: `return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Games', 'App\Models\Teams','id','home_id');` ... with this I get all Home games of the club. But how can I add an `or` so I get all games where teams of the club are home or guest teams

Comment: You can use `where` on that relationship to `filter` it further

Comment: `...->games()` only returns games where the home_id is an team_id of the club. When I remove the last two parameters (like your example), I get an SQL exception. I can't add an array to the `secondKey` parameter of the `hasManyThrough` function (e.g. `['home_id','guest_id']`.

Comment: thank you for your help! But is it possible to merge them and order them after the merge?

Comment: Gave you an example of how u can merge these 2 relationships, notice how I called relationships without `brackets`, that means I'm accessing the value and not the underlying `query`

Comment: But I can't use ->orderBy(..) after the merge. I found ->union(), but it always brings up the error "Different number of columns", which is not possible

Comment: That is because object thats returned from the `merge` is not `Eloquent Builder` which has the method `orderBy`, but it's a `Collection` which has `sortBy` :) To see all available methods you can use on `$merged`, take a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#available-methods)

Comment: Also, after the merge, I recommend you to add the `unique()` method to the returning collection because there'll be a lot of duplication (a same game is played between the home and away team, so it will exist in both collections).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out an important thing I totally forgot @HCK

Comment: I can't use sortBy('date') - because the merged array added numberic keys. After I removed them with ->all() I can't use ->sortyBy() because it is an array... this is so frustrating...

Comment: SortBy also offers a callable instead of a `attribute name` to sort by on. I will update my answer with an example right now

Comment: Glad you resolved it and hope you learnt a bit :) You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

When you define that Club `hasMany` games you are indicating that game has a foreign key called `club_id` pointing to Club. `belongsTo` is the same but in the other way. These need to be coherent with what you have on your database, that means that you need to have defined those keys as foreign keys on your tables.

Comment: The games table only have home and guest team as foreign keys that point to team. Team has a foreign key called club_id which points to club

Comment: When you say `$this->hasMany('App\Models\Games')` on the games function of the Club class you are indicating that is `Game` that has a `club_id`, that's why "a club has many games".

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

**Club model**

```
public function games()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Games');
    }
```

**Game model**

```
public function homeTeam()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Team','home_id');
    }

    public function guestTeam()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Team','guest_id');
    }
```

**Your Query like**

```
Club::where('id',$id)->has('games.guestTeam')->get();
```